# Move to SDCard option Disabled

Tags: app2sd, samsung-galaxy-music-duos

I have a Samsung Galaxy Music Duos GT-S6012, which I got 2 days back. It has android 4.03.

The problem is I am not able to move my games and some apps to the SD card. The move to SD card button which is normally visible in the application manager is not visible in my phone. Please help me.

Is it default behavior on the phone, or is there a problem?

I even tried the `move2sd` app, but it did not work.

Comment: can you check your SD card is mounted correctly? are you able access files from sd card?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Some apps will not work if they are moved to the SD card, because of some dependencies with the internal storage. So, expect some of those apps to have disabled `Move to SD card` buttons.

Comment: no man..all the apps are shown like tat.!! even the games cannot be moved..pls help..
and the version is 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy S Duos have the same problem.

To solve this, root your phone, and try moving the apps. If you have no success, then try a custom ROM (I'd recommend CyanogenMod).